# where is "build-depends: " in Cabal

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I need to use `System. Random`
but I can't find where the `build-depends:` option is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cabal init` to create a cabal project, and add `random` to the `build-dependencies` stanza in the `*.cabal` file it generates.